# Debugging a vb.net SQL command

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, .net-2.0

I am attempting to call SQL stored procedure that does an INSERT. However, when I walkthrough my vb.net code, I get a message saying **"Procedure or function sp_InsertARPlanner has too many arguments specified."**

I have double checked, but the SQL string in VB has the same # of params as in the stored procedure.

Any ideas how I can debug this?

**Update**

```
    SQLCmd.CommandText = "sp_InsertARPlanner"
    SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Origin", Trim(txtOrigin.Text))
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Destination", Trim(txtDest.Text))
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Miles", iMiles)
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate", iAvgRateperMile)
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinCost", dMinCost)
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zone", sZone)
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LaneHaulCost", dLaneHaulCost)
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalCost", dTotalCost)              
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalWithSurch", dTotalWithSurch)
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvgTypeRate", sAvgTypeRate)    
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvgLoads", sAvgLoads)          
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FuelLevel", dFuelPercent)    
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fuel", dFuelAmount)      
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AverageRateAmount", dAverageRateAmount)
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Floor", decFloor)
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RainBulkRate", decBulkRate)
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RateComments", txtRateDesc..Text)
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PremiumField", txtPremium.Text)
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EquipCategory", Trim(cboEquipType.Text))
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdateDate", DateTime.Now)
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FreightDesc", "txtFreightDesc.Text")

Try
    SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    SQLCon.Close()
    SQLCmd.Parameters.Clear()
    Exit Sub
End Try
```

---

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertARPlanner]
    (@Origin nvarchar(150)
           ,@Destination nvarchar(150)
           ,@Miles nvarchar(50)
           ,@Rate nvarchar(5)
           ,@MinCost decimal(5,2)
           ,@Zone varchar(3)
           ,@LaneHaulCost decimal(5, 2)
           ,@TotalCost decimal(5, 2)
           ,@TotalWithSurch decimal(5, 2)
           ,@AvgTypeRate varchar(50)
           ,@AvgLoads varchar(4)
           ,@FuelPercent decimal(5,2)
           ,@FuelAmount decimal(5,2)
           ,@AverageRateAmount decimal(5,2)
           ,@Floor decimal(5, 2)
           ,@RainBulkRate decimal(5, 2)
           ,@RateComments nvarchar(50)
           ,@PremiumField nvarchar(50)
           ,@EquipCategory nvarchar(50)
           ,@UpdateDate datetime
           ,@FreightDesc nvarchar(50))
```

Comment: If you can post the code and the SQL procedure, maybe someone here can find out that extra argument for you ;)

Comment: Are you using parametered queries or a straight string INSERT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Don't start your stored procedure name with `sp_` That stands for system procedure in sql server, and will cause sql server to do extra work looking for your procedure (this isn't your problem though, but it's good practice).
2. Take the procedure string that the program has created and paste it into the sql server management studio window, to make sure that it works there.  If not then you know where the issue is.
3. If so, make sure you are hitting the db you think your are.  If you have multiple environments it maybe that the database you are hitting isn't the one that has the correct number of parameters.

Comment: crazy resolution, but the cmd object had not been closed in a prior routine, and so was point at another stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

When stepping through your code, there will be a point where the stored procedure and its parameters have been populated, perhaps in a SqlCommand object. You can **capture that sproc call at a breakpoint**. Then, copy it to your query tool, call EXEC and paste the sproc call in. Then run it. That way, you will be executing the exact stored procedure call that your code is sending.

If you provide more details of your code, we can be more specific on exactly how to capture the sproc call.